# Вернуть вместо null 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

Хочу вернуть вместо null - 0, пробую через COALESCE, но не выходит, ругается на синтаксис перед `)) proc_month`

```
WITH cte as (
select 
        type_room_rus, period,
        case 
            when type_room_rus is not null then sum(price) / sum(area) end as price_g,
        lag(sum(price) / sum(area), 1) over (
            partition by type_room_rus
            order by period
        ) prev
    from pbi#12_everyweekly
    where status_kv = 'AVAILABLE' and zhk is not null
    group by type_room_rus, period
)

select 
    type_room_rus,
    period,
    price_g,
    COALESCE(format (
        ((price_g - prev) / prev) * 100,
        'n'
    ), 0) proc_month
    from cte
```

Данная ошибка вылазит, после моего запроса

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 Ошибка преобразования значения
> nvarchar "4,98" в тип данных int.

Скриншот, где нужно заменить null на 0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот в упор не вижу нуля...

Comment: чтобы вывести 0 вместо null можно использовать либо `select ISNULL(null, 0)` либо `SELECT COALESCE(null, 0)` а не то что у вас тут

Comment: Ну а где второй агрумент?

Comment: @Akina, дополнил запрос и прикрепил скрин

Comment: Теперь и COALESCE() пропала..

Comment: @Akina, вот теперь точно все добавил :-)

Comment: *Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 Ошибка преобразования значения nvarchar "4,98" в тип данных int.* - вот именно так, с запятой вместо десятичной точки, в значении? Так надо в итоговом столбце? Вынесите format за пределы COALESCE.

Comment: @Akina, да именно такая ошибка.
Теперь ошибка: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Тип данных аргумента int недопустим для аргумента 2 функции format.

Comment: попробуйте вы внимательно со скобками разобраться, вроде не сложная задача должна быть

Comment: Напишите вычисляющее выражение. Оберните его в COALESCE. Оберните полученное в FORMAT. Ну тривиальная же вещь - всего и надо что аккуратности...

Comment: Всем спасибо, решил в case все посчитать и обернуть в COALESCE. Вот так:
COALESCE((case when price_g is not null then (price_g - prev) / prev * 100 end), 0) as proc_month

Comment: @sk1p96 Зачем вам `coalesce`, если вы в явную `is not null` проверяете? )  Что-то одно тут нужно, насколько я понимаю - или так делать, или эдак

Comment: Я же проверяю поле price_g, а мне надо чтобы в новом поле proc_month null заменялся на 0. По итогу работает так как мне надо.

Comment: Всё одно масло масляное получилось.

Comment: ), '0') proc_month

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> COALESCE(format (
>         ((price_g - prev) / prev) * 100,
>         'n'
>     ), 0) proc_month
> ```

```
format(
  COALESCE((price_g - prev) / prev, 0) * 100,
  'n'
) proc_month
```

Comment: а не подскажите какая разница между `isnull` и `COALESCE` по вашему ?, потому как я всегда использую исНюль, а про второе только не помню, сейчас увидела, думаю а почему бы не попробовать где т заменить если есть разница ....

Comment: @Dev18 второе в стандарте описано и принимать может несколько аргументов, вернет первый не null

Comment: @Dev18, есть подозрение, что isnull - функция, а coalesce - нет. Впрочем, я не уверен и надо проверять.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала вычисляешь данные, в конце приводишь к нужному виду:

```
    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT  type_room_rus,
                period,
                CASE WHEN type_room_rus IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(price) / SUM(area) END AS price_g,
                LAG(SUM(price) / SUM(area), 1) OVER(PARTITION BY type_room_rus ORDER BY period) AS prev
        FROM pbi#12_everyweekly
        WHERE status_kv = 'AVAILABLE'
            AND zhk IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY type_room_rus, period
    )
    SELECT type_room_rus,
            period,
            price_g,
            COALESCE((price_g - prev) / prev * 100, 0) AS proc_month
    FROM CTE
```